# Get changed file path via Grunt and use it to pass as an argument for another task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

It's interesting how can I get file path which file has changed via Grunt. Then use last changed file as argument for another task.

Actually I want to get file path and send it to `grunt-shell` to do some `x [filename]` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done working solution with this **gruntfile**: https://gist.github.com/nikoloza/515f4d4cac656cbe2594

Someone may find it useful.